# Destructuring props in pure function components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Suppose we have the following pure function:

```
const HeaderComponent = () => (
  <h1> Title <h1>
)

export default HeaderComponent
```

Now I need to receive the new title from props, so we often destructure `this.props` to avoid accessing `title` with `this.props.title` and in the render method we will have something like:

```
render() {
  const {Title} = this.props;
  return(
    <h1> {Title} </h1>
  )
}
```

The thing is we have to extend `React.Component` class to access render method.

Is it possible to use the destructure in pure functions?

```
const HeaderComponent = props => (
   // const {Title} = this.props;
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it like this.  I also find it a nice way of making the function self documenting.

```
const HeaderComponent = ({ title }) => (
   <h1>{ title }<h1>
)
```

Also can set default values

```
const HeaderComponent = ({ title: 'Default Title' }) => (
   <h1>{ title }<h1>
)
```

UPDATE: 
As [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder) points out, `Title` is capitalized in your examples above.  In the text portion it is lowercase; as that is the norm, I have used the lowercase version

Comment: This is the better way.

Answer (score 1):

For your specific situation, see [ken4z's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42113832/157247), as parameter destructuring is the most concise way to do that.

But in the general case: If you have logic you need to put in the arrow function prior to the return, just use the verbose form of arrow function:

```
const HeaderComponent = props => {
  const {Title} = props;
  // ....more logic can go here...
  return <h1>{Title}<h1>;
};
```

But again, you don't need that *just* to grab `Title` from `props`.

---

*(Side note: It's unusual to capitalize the `T` in `title` when it's a property name or variable name...)*